# Error 404 before deleting specific module folder in Odoo 10

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I have placed an Odoo 8 module in the applications folder and then I have deleted it because i found a 10 version from that, then it shows me the following error:

```
GET https://dm06069.mywebsite.com/web/image/ir.ui.menu/443/web_icon_data 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
web.assets_common.js:561 GET https://dm06069.mywebsite.com/web/static/lib/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0 net::ERR_ABORTED
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:561
fire @ web.assets_common.js:541
fireWith @ web.assets_common.js:546
ready @ web.assets_common.js:554
completed @ web.assets_common.js:555
web.assets_common.js:561 GET https://dm06069.mywebsite.com/backend_theme_v10/static/src/font/Roboto-Regular.ttf net::ERR_ABORTED
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:561
fire @ web.assets_common.js:541
fireWith @ web.assets_common.js:546
ready @ web.assets_common.js:554
completed @ web.assets_common.js:555
web.assets_common.js:2939 GET https://dm06069.mywebsite.com/web_editor/static/src/xml/ace.xml 404 (NOT FOUND)
load_xml @ web.assets_common.js:2939
add_template @ web.assets_common.js:2923
loadXML @ web.assets_common.js:3053
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:3719
process_job @ web.assets_common.js:3000
process_jobs @ web.assets_common.js:3006
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:3001
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:547
fire @ web.assets_common.js:541
fireWith @ web.assets_common.js:546
deferred.(anonymous function) @ web.assets_common.js:548
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:3737
fire @ web.assets_common.js:541
fireWith @ web.assets_common.js:546
ready @ web.assets_common.js:554
completed @ web.assets_common.js:555
web.assets_common.js:3038 GET https://dm06069.mywebsite.com/web/webclient/locale/es_ES net::ERR_ABORTED
loadJS @ web.assets_common.js:3038
load_js @ web.assets_common.js:3151
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:3151
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:547
fire @ web.assets_common.js:541
fireWith @ web.assets_common.js:546
deferred.(anonymous function) @ web.assets_common.js:548
fire @ web.assets_common.js:541
fireWith @ web.assets_common.js:546
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:547
fire @ web.assets_common.js:541
fireWith @ web.assets_common.js:546
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:547
fire @ web.assets_common.js:541
fireWith @ web.assets_common.js:546
done @ web.assets_common.js:937
callback @ web.assets_common.js:957
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ web.assets_common.js:954
ajax @ web.assets_common.js:930
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:3030
genericJsonRpc @ web.assets_common.js:3028
jsonRpc @ web.assets_common.js:3030
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:3164
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:547
fire @ web.assets_common.js:541
add @ web.assets_common.js:542
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:547
each @ web.assets_common.js:370
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:547
Deferred @ web.assets_common.js:548
then @ web.assets_common.js:547
rpc @ web.assets_common.js:3161
load_translations @ web.assets_common.js:3024
load_translations @ web.assets_common.js:3151
load_modules @ web.assets_common.js:3150
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:3142
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:547
fire @ web.assets_common.js:541
fireWith @ web.assets_common.js:546
deferred.(anonymous function) @ web.assets_common.js:548
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:3207
fire @ web.assets_common.js:541
fireWith @ web.assets_common.js:546
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:547
fire @ web.assets_common.js:541
fireWith @ web.assets_common.js:546
done @ web.assets_common.js:937
callback @ web.assets_common.js:957
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ web.assets_common.js:954
ajax @ web.assets_common.js:930
jQuery.(anonymous function) @ web.assets_common.js:941
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:3152
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:3207
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:547
fire @ web.assets_common.js:541
add @ web.assets_common.js:542
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:547
each @ web.assets_common.js:370
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:547
Deferred @ web.assets_common.js:548
then @ web.assets_common.js:547
Mutex.exec @ web.assets_common.js:3207
load_qweb @ web.assets_common.js:3152
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:3142
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:547
fire @ web.assets_common.js:541
add @ web.assets_common.js:542
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:547
each @ web.assets_common.js:370
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:547
Deferred @ web.assets_common.js:548
then @ web.assets_common.js:547
session_init @ web.assets_common.js:3142
session_bind @ web.assets_common.js:3142
(anonymous) @ web.assets_backend.js:1855
process_job @ web.assets_common.js:3000
process_jobs @ web.assets_common.js:3006
define @ web.assets_common.js:2990
(anonymous) @ web.assets_backend.js:1855
web.assets_common.js:3038 Error loading file https://dm06069.mywebsite.com/web/webclient/locale/es_ES
script.onerror @ web.assets_common.js:3038
web:1 GET https://dm06069.mywebsite.com/web/static/lib/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.5.0 net::ERR_ABORTED
web.assets_common.js:2939 GET https://dm06069.mywebsite.com/web_editor/static/src/xml/editor.xml 404 (NOT FOUND)
load_xml @ web.assets_common.js:2939
add_template @ web.assets_common.js:2923
loadXML @ web.assets_common.js:3053
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:3054
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:2923
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:2938
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
load_xml @ web.assets_common.js:2939
add_template @ web.assets_common.js:2923
loadXML @ web.assets_common.js:3053
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:3719
process_job @ web.assets_common.js:3000
process_jobs @ web.assets_common.js:3006
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:3001
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:547
fire @ web.assets_common.js:541
fireWith @ web.assets_common.js:546
deferred.(anonymous function) @ web.assets_common.js:548
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:3737
fire @ web.assets_common.js:541
fireWith @ web.assets_common.js:546
ready @ web.assets_common.js:554
completed @ web.assets_common.js:555
web.assets_common.js:561 GET https://dm06069.mywebsite.com/backend_theme_v10/static/src/img/material-background.jpg 404 (NOT FOUND)
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:561
fire @ web.assets_common.js:541
fireWith @ web.assets_common.js:546
ready @ web.assets_common.js:554
completed @ web.assets_common.js:555
web:1 GET https://dm06069.mywebsite.com/web/static/lib/fontawesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.5.0 net::ERR_ABORTED
web.assets_common.js:2939 GET https://dm06069.mywebsite.com/web_editor/static/src/xml/snippets.xml 404 (NOT FOUND)
load_xml @ web.assets_common.js:2939
add_template @ web.assets_common.js:2923
loadXML @ web.assets_common.js:3053
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:3054
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:2923
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:2938
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
load_xml @ web.assets_common.js:2939
add_template @ web.assets_common.js:2923
loadXML @ web.assets_common.js:3053
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:3054
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:2923
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:2938
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
load_xml @ web.assets_common.js:2939
add_template @ web.assets_common.js:2923
loadXML @ web.assets_common.js:3053
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:3719
process_job @ web.assets_common.js:3000
process_jobs @ web.assets_common.js:3006
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:3001
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:547
fire @ web.assets_common.js:541
fireWith @ web.assets_common.js:546
deferred.(anonymous function) @ web.assets_common.js:548
(anonymous) @ web.assets_common.js:3737
fire @ web.assets_common.js:541
fireWith @ web.assets_common.js:546
ready @ web.assets_common.js:554
completed @ web.assets_common.js:555_common.js:555
```

I have found that probably this ia an error from **openerp**.py but I can't find the following one because every module in Odoo has his own.I'm not sure which files should I have to modify and how, some help?

Comment: Try to upgrade this module after commenting all files registered in menifest file.
If already uninstalled, try to upgrade all.
NOTE: You need to upgrade from command line if can't from front end.

Comment: just put the code that you removed back and uninstall the module before you remove it. i think this will work

Comment: thank you very much for help,at the end the problem was cos version is 10 I tried to install version 8, the base and some __openerp__.py had been overrided with wrong configurations, like, strangely, base and my postgre. I had to do a rebase and then proceed to the installation of the valid module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to incompatibilities between versions.
I finally managed it getting back the at the properly git version with `git checkout HASHNUMBER`

First I had to locate the git registry with a properly configuration that i had before to broke it up:

`git log`

It returns something like this:

```
commit eb9b03c2e22305c965b610aa84a7d316e5cb208d
Author: Marc Decline <marcdecline@marcdecline.(none)>
Date:   Mon Apr 3 10:15:12 2018 +0200

    commit21
```

Then `git checkout eb9b03c2e22305c965b610aa84a7d316e5cb208d` to get back.

Finally restarting service with

`service openerp-server stop`

`service postgresql restart`

`service openerp-server start`